# going to fragment from recyclerview and when i press back button recyclerview adding same data again

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

when user click on link, from RecyclerView i am calling another fragment to show its content, im using `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` to get back on previous fragment when i remove this there is no problem but backpage not saving, help me

so here i wants to go to back page but without re adding data.

and my second question is i wants to add backbutton icon on toolbar/action bar when i go to second fragment only for that fragment

fragment one :

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.notification_recyclerview);
        load_data_from_server();
        linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        notificationAdapter=new NotificationAdapter(notification,getActivity());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);


        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                //super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                if(linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()==notification.size()-1)
                {
                    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
                    Cursor all_data=databaseHelper.get_all_scrolled_data_from_news(notification.get(notification.size()-1).getServer_id());
                    if(all_data.getCount()>0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"total"+all_data.getCount(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            while (all_data.moveToNext())
                            {
                                Notification_Data n_data=new Notification_Data(all_data.getInt(0),all_data.getInt(1),all_data.getString(2),all_data.getString(3));
                                notification.add(n_data);
                            }
                            notificationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            all_data.close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No more data available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }

            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.notification_swiperefresh);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                refreshItems();
            }
        });




        return view;
    }
```

recyclerAdapter class :

```
NotificationDescriptionFragment noti_desc=new NotificationDescriptionFragment();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("server_id",noti_data.get(position).getServer_id());
                noti_desc.setArguments(bundle);
                MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)context;
                fragmentTransaction=mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container,noti_desc);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();





public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        //int value=getArguments().getInt("server_id");

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_description, container, false);
        TextView notification_content=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_content);


        databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        Cursor c=databaseHelper.get_contnt_by_id_from_news(server_id);
        while (c.moveToNext())
        {

            notification_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(c.getString(0)));

        }


        return view;
    }
```

screenshots :

1 - 1st fragment where i created list with recycler view

[image]

now when user click on any item going to another fragment for content this is
second fragment :

[image]

and when i press back button from 2nd fragment 
same data adding into recycler view here is screen shot :
[image]

Comment: What happens if you close and reopen the app. Does it shows unique or repeated item after launching?

Answer (score 2):

Clear the list (i.e notification in your case) before add.

Comment: i done this , in my fragment1  List<Data> new_data;

and in oncreate method i initilize it as new_data=new ArrayList<>();

voting you up